# Extract string with regular expression using OR with multiple true values what result it returns?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I could use some explanation about how does str.extract work with regex in python.

for example, I have some strings

```
6/18/1985 Primary Care Doctor
In 1980, the patient was living in Naples and de
2008 partial thyroidectomy
2/6/96 sleep studyPain Treatment Pain Level
```

I use the following code to extract the dates in the strings:

```
str.extract('((\d{1,2}[/]\d{1,2}[/]\d{2,4})|(\d{4}))')
```

this code works perfectly with my original stings, and output with:

```
6/18/1985
1980
2008
2/6/96
```

However, my question is since `6/18/1985` technically match my second condition`(\d{4})` with a return value of `1985`, then why my code still works and return with a value of `6/18/1985`?

I think my biggest confusion comes from how does the `|`(or) operator works in the code where there are multiple true results, and which one should return?

Any thoughts?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Regex is greedy, and it does not do multiple overlapping matches. It matches your first option and therefore it does not check the other options. You could say you got lucky by putting the full date group first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this regex matching

```
import re
>>> re.findall('(\d{1,2}[/]\d{1,2}[/]\d{2,4})|(\d{4})|([P])', "6/18/1985 2234 Primary Care Doctor")
[('6/18/1985', '', ''), ('', '2234', ''), ('', '', 'P')]
    ^^^1st group^^^      ^^^2nd group^^^  ^^^3rd group^^^
```

As we can see from the above matching, since we have specified 3 matching groups in the regex pattern, the regex engine will try to match every separate group in your target string and return that group if at-least one of the matches is non-empty. Here, from the string `"6/18/1985 2234 Primary Care Doctor"`, each capturing group was able to find at-least one non-empty match, hence returning that group. OR tells the regex to try finding each pattern in the string to find at-least one non-empty match and if so, return the whole group. On the other hand, if we try to match with above pattern in this string

```
>>> re.findall('(\d{1,2}[/]\d{1,2}[/]\d{2,4})|(\d{4})|([P])', "6/18/1985 Primary Care Doctor")
[('6/18/1985', '', ''), ('', '', 'P')]
   ^^^1st group^^^      ^^^3rd group^^^
```

We can see that we didn't get any matches for the second pattern `(\d{4})` since this pattern doesn't find a single non-empty match in the string (no 4 integers), hence only returning the matches for 1st and 3rd patterns which contain at-least return groups containing non-empty matches.

In your case, the regex was always able to find at-least one non-empty match in each of the pandas' rows of strings like below:

```
>>> df = pd.Series(["6/18/1985 Primary Care Doctor", "In 1980, the patient was living in Naples and de"])
>>> df.str.extract('(\d{1,2}[/]\d{1,2}[/]\d{2,4})|(\d{4})')
           0     1
0  6/18/1985   NaN
1        NaN  1980
```

You can see that there are NaN values for the second pattern in first string and for the first pattern in the second string.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I think the key here is the order matters. but I have one more question regarding your answer, if I switch the order to  `re.findall('(\d{4})|(\d{1,2}[/]\d{1,2}[/]\d{2,4})|([P])', "6/18/1985 Primary Care Doctor")` I'm putting the `(\d{4})` to the first group, why I still do not get any matches in the first group,shouldn't return 1985 in the first group?

Comment: That's because it starts matching from the start of the string, when done so, you can find a match for `6/18/1985` with you second regex pattern at `start=0` itself but `(\d{4})` can't (`start=0` gives first four characters as `6/18` which don’t match you first pattern), to find a match for this pattern, you will have to increment your `start` upto `start=5` but you don’t get a chance to do so, since a match has been found from second pattern at `start=0` itself, it simply returns from there only in a greedy manner. @FrankZ.

Comment: wow, thank you so much, your explanation really clears a lot of confusions I recently have.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> As the target string is scanned, REs separated by '|' are tried from left to right.